# Handle worksheets in PowerShell ForEach loop

Tags: excel, powershell

I have ForEach loop in a PowerShell script that is attempting to run through every file that has been created in a folder in the last 2 hours. It will take each file, delete certain columns, and rows, and will only leave one column with header ActiveFaults. It will then sort/group and format, and will give me a string of ActiveFaults for each file.

The output of my script is what I need, but it is taking A LOT of time to process. Is there a more efficient way to do this? Also, every now and then, it gives me an error saying that "the object does not contain a Workbooks.Open() method "...Any ideas on why this is? And why that issue would be intermittent? Thanks in advance.

```
$PathMX1005 = "\source"
filesMX1005 = Get-ChildItem $PathMX1005 -recurse -include *1Hz*.csv | Where { $_.CreationTime -ge [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-180) }

Copy-Item $filesMX1005 \destination -Recurse

$files2MX1005 = Get-ChildItem \destination -Recurse

foreach($file in $files2MX1005) {

    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
    $Excel.visible = $false
    $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.open($file.FullName) 
    $range = $Workbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:FZ1").EntireColumn 
    $range2 = $Workbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A34").EntireRow
    $range.Delete()
    $range2.Delete()
    $Excel.DisplayAlerts=$False
    $Workbook.SaveAs("c:\StrippedHeader.csv")

    $FaultsMX1005 = Import-CSV ":\StrippedHeader.csv" | Group-Object ActiveFaults | foreach-object { $_.group | select -last 1} | Out-String 

    $Excel.Workbooks.Close()
    $Excel.Quit()
```

Comment: `$files2MX1005` does not filter for excel documents is my first concern. There is also no need to keep making the com object `$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application` should be able to run that line once _outside_ the loop. Are these actually just csv files? we dont need to use the com object for those. I don't see what you populate `$FaultsMX1005 ` and you are missing the closing brace from `ForEach`

Answer (score 0):

I see you have `.csv` in your code a couple of times which makes me think that you do not need to be using the Excel COM Object at all.

So to start we change `$files2MX1005` so it filters for only csv files and the we use `Import-CSV` on each of those files. If you have a column called `ActiveFaults` we can just select that and move on.

```powershell
$files2MX1005 = Get-ChildItem C:\temp\files -Recurse -Filter *.csv

foreach($file in $files2MX1005){
    $ActiveFaults = Import-CSV $file | Select ActiveFaults 
    # Further process $ActiveFaults
}
```

I'm not sure what else you are doing with that data but I think this would be forward progress for you.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for your reply. Each of these CSVs are 5000 rows by 300 columns long, importing them takes a very long time, this is why I am opening excel, and deleting rows/columns before I import it. Does that not make sense? Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: @CarlosSousa I have not tried bench-marking you Excel code compared to this method so I am not sure which is faster. While that does seem like a lot  of data I have worked with larger CSVs with good efficiency. Try it first and maybe you way is faster. It just seemed inefficient to use excel for csv data.

Comment: as Import-CSV reads the whole file to memory, it would be better to use a streamreader reading line by line.